# Mapping a unique list of items shows warning Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm mapping a list of routes as screens in react-native and I'm sure that every item in that list has a unique `name` property.

When mapping through that list the console shows a warning that reads: **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

```
export const homeStack = [
  {name: 'Notifs', component: Notifs, isPrivate: true},
  {name: 'NewsScreen', component: News, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'Map', component: Map, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'ProfInfo', component: ProfInfo, isPrivate: true},
  {name: 'Passes', component: MyPasses, isPrivate: true},
  {name: 'DebtPasses', component: DebtPasses, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'ViolPass', component: ViolPasses, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'SSS', component: FAQ, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'ContactUs', component: ContactUs, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'Permissions', component: Permissions, isPrivate: true},
  {name: 'Logout', component: Logout, isPrivate: true},
  {name: 'PassRes', component: PassRes, isPrivate: true},
  {name: 'Welcome', component: Intro, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'Payment', component: PaymentPreviewScreen, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'Login', component: Login, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'OTPScreen', component: OTPScreen, isPrivate: false},
  {name: 'Sign Up', component: Registration, isPrivate: false},
];
```

this is my list and I'm trying to understand what is wrong with it that says mapping this like:

```
{homeStack.map(
         ({name, component, isPrivate}, index) => {
             console.log('stack', index);
                              return (
                                    <Stack.Screen
                                      key={index}
                                      name={name}
                                      options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        gestureEnabled: true,
                                        gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
                                        transitionSpec: {
                                          open: openConf,
                                          close: closeConf,
                                        },
                                        cardStyleInterpolator:
                                          CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS,
                                      }}
                                      component={component}
                                    />
                                  )
```

This is supposedly not unique? Is it because of the way I'm mapping?

Incase there's confusion here's the TabNav mapping and the list;

```
export const tabs = [
  { name: 'Home', component: Home, isPrivate: false, iconName: 'home' },
  { name: 'Vehicles', component: MyPlates, isPrivate: true, iconName: 'car' },
  { name: 'Summary', component: Summary, isPrivate: true, iconName: 'book' },
  { name: 'Profile', component: MyProfile, isPrivate: true, iconName: 'user' },
];

{tabs.map(({name, component, isPrivate, iconName}) => <Tab.Screen key={name} /> )}
```

Comment: There is a typo in your map function.

Comment: The typo occurred when I was simplifying it for asking a question. Please don't worry about it

Comment: I mean the syntax is incorrect. The map function should have a callback function as a parameter, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Also if your code is valid and the data does not change, it is safe to use the index as a key.

Comment: I'll edit my question to include the whole mapping process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
{homestack.map((i) => (
   <Stack.Screen key={i.name} /> )}
))}
```

Following the syntax for the arrow function is like this based on their [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
// Arrow function
map((element) => { /* ... */ })
map((element, index) => { /* ... */ })
map((element, index, array) => { /* ... */ })
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help the fact is that I'm deconstructing the `i` element here by using the syntax `{name,component,isPrivate}`

Comment: @OrçunGüler can you check if all the components being mapped in the homestack has any list/item that's being mapped as well

Comment: No all the parts of the list is either static or a react component

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the case is a component being mapped has a list/item that's being mapped that doesn't have a unique key prop. Kinda difficult to visualize with minimal example we have and can see ^^